# What does this symbol mean?

Tags: discussion, comments, symbols

Really not about Ubuntu, but I have recently noticed some people using this symbol `<3` on Ask Ubuntu and Ask Ubuntu Meta. What does it mean? Is it some secret code that only certain people understand?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a heart, tilted 90 degrees clockwise.

❤️ ~ `<3`